# Simple SQL in exec statement does not accept the database name extracted inside the exec

Tags: sql, exec

I have following exec statement and when I replace Use[HUM_FM_1_SYNTQ_TEST] with @DBName I get an error database '@DBName' does not exist.  I tried [''+@DBName+''] and get similar error.  What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
exec(' 
-- Get position number and dbname
DECLARE @posNo bigint
DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @sampleDate nvarchar (30)
DECLARE @sampleTime nvarchar (30)
DECLARE @runID bigint

Set @posNo = (select PositionNumber from ' + @temp_table_distincts_withPositions + 
' where [COutputData_3_Segment_Number] = ' + @segment_no + ')
Set @DBName = (select DBName from ' + @temp_table_distincts_withPositions + 
' where [COutputData_3_Segment_Number] = ' + @segment_no + ')
Set @runID = (select RunID from ' + @temp_table_distincts_withPositions + 
' where [COutputData_3_Segment_Number] = ' + @segment_no + ')

select @runID

-- Query the appropriate seriesvariables table

-- Get Sample Date
Use [HUM_FM_1_SYNTQ_TEST]
Set @sampleDate = (Select seriesvariables_value from
(
select *, row_number() over 
(order by SeriesVariables_ID asc) as rownum from Seriesvariables where 
SeriesVariables_Label = ''Enter Tablet Segment Pull Date'' and
Series_ID = @runID) as tbl1 
where rownum = @posNo)

select @sampleDate

' )
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this running under?

Answer (score 1):

@DBName is a variable within your dynamic SQL string, not a direct identifier of a table, so you can't use it directly in a USE statement, nor can you transform it into a standard identifier at the same level of dynamic SQL.

I think the only way to do what you want to do here without some radical restructuring (which I can't help you with because I don't know what the larger scenario is) is to use doubly dynamic SQL -- in other words, use your dynamic SQL to create a SQL string that you then execute.

This is a bad idea (it's confusing and hard to maintain), so I suggest spending some time seeing if you can restructure the problem.